# Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse com um trecho desse código SQL e Python

Tags: sql, python

Estou tentando capturar um flag do site Hacker101 CFT e acabei me deparando com um trecho de código.

NESSA PARTE ESPECÍFICA:

```
 if cur.execute('SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=\'%s\'' % request.form['username'].replace('%', '%%')) == 0:
```

gostaria de saber o significado desses símbolos (\'%s\'' %) na linguagem, depois da palavra username, pretendo estudar essa parte para entender o código por completo porém não sei qual palavra chave utilizar para pesquisar sobre esses (\'%s\'' %) símbolos.

```
// TRECHO DA MENSAGEM DE ERRO COMPLETO

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 145, in do_login
    if cur.execute('SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=\'%s\'' % request.form['username'].replace('%', '%%')) == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 255, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''''' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse %s é do String Format do Python, serve para você formatar strings, veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
name = "Mundo"
print("Olá  %s!" %name)
```

A saída do comando abaixo é:

```
Olá Mundo!
```

O %s é usado quando vc vai substituir por uma string, tem também o %d para quando for um numeral.
Você pode ver mais sobre string format [aqui](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente! Muito obrigado Murilo.

Comment: @RaiuriSantos se a resposta lhe foi útil considere marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.